# Get the value of a key of each hash inside an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have got an array of hashes, for example:

```
[{"id" => "1", "name" => "Name 1"},
 {"id" => "2", "name" => "Name 2"}, 
 {"id" => "3", "name" => "Name 3"}]
```

I would like to get the value of the key `"name"` for each hash, similar to this:

```
["Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3"]
```

I looked around for quite a while but couldn't find the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simplest to use [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) for this purpose:

```
array = [{"id" => "1", "name" => "Name 1"}, {"id" => "2", "name" => "Name 2"}, {"id" => "3", "name" => "Name 3"}]
array.map { |hash| hash['name'] }
# => ["Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3"]
```

Comment: So simple.. Thanks :) I really need to practice more in the console.